# How to specify attributes like "highlightbackground" for the OptionMenu widget in tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, attributes

I have been experimenting with the OptionMenu widget in tkinter, and noticed that whenever I try to specify a different attribute, like the `highlightbackground` option, it seems to think that I am telling it a value to display in the dropdown. I have this:

```
self.color_menu = OptionMenu(self.main, self.colorForMenuText, *self.colors,highlightbackground = self.color)# 
self.color_menu.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.4, anchor = "center")
```

I expect it to, well, perform the said function. However, instead it crashes and spits all this out:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/odimartino/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "PhotoWall.py", line 29, in setting
self.color_menu = OptionMenu(self.main, self.colorForMenuText, *self.colors, highlightbackground = self.color)#
File "/Users/odimartino/.pyenv/versions/3.4.2/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3331, in __init__
raise TclError('unknown option -'+kwargs.keys()[0])
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Just in case I didn't express myself clearly enough above (clarity isn't my strong point), my question is: how can I tell this widget what to do when it thinks I'm telling it something else?

Comment: The optionmenu doesn't take options like you think it does. Is there some documentation that you're reading that says it has these options?

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, I assume it's a widget. And, unless I'm about to be told otherwise (happens to me a lot), tkinter widgets take these options. Just like buttons, which I have used highlightbackground for.

Comment: The first step should always be to read the documentation when your assumptions don't seem to be working for you.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for responding, even though I can be a little ignorant. This is the learning process! Maybe some day I will be a world class developer. Until then... Well, I can dream big... Anyway, the effbot article I was reading didn't say anything about it being an unusual widget... So I assumed that it was exactly like all the widgets I had seen thus far. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OptionMenu isn't a traditional tkinter widget. It does not accept options on the command line. You have to create the widget, and then call the `configure` method on the object that it returns.

```
var = tk.StringVar()
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, "one", "two", "three")
om.configure(highlightcolor = "red")
```

To get a reference to the associated menu, use `winfo_children`, which returns a list with one element:

```
menu = om.winfo_children()[0]
menu.configure(...)
```

The reason for this is that the underlying toolkit "tk" has no optionmenu widget. It's a convenience function that creates a menu button and a menu, and links them together. Since it's a function rather than a class (at the tk level) it doesn't take option/value pairs like normal widgets.

Comment: Oh my. Even though I excepted your answer yesterday it took until today for me to fully grasp the awesomeness of how exactly that logic works. Wow. Pretty neat stuff.